# Make a string "regexp-safe"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wan't to make a string regexp safe in Ruby.

I have:

```
comment = "Just a comment someone makes"
Word.find(:all).each do |word|
  comment.gsub!(%r{#{word}\s*}," ")
end
```

This replaces all words I've stored in the model Word with an empty space. The problem is if *word* contains for instance a left parenthesis "(" it will fail. Is there a better way of doing this or at least make *word* regexp safe? *Word* may contain any type of character.

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [Regexp.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001195)